# set html inputbox to readonly if it has a value

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, readonly

I have the following piece of code that creates an input box:

```
<input name="university" type="text" id="university" value="<? echo $uni_name['name'] ?>">
```

The `$uni_name['name']` variable can sometimes have a value, however it can sometimes be empty. If the variable has a value I need the input's readonly value to be set to true.

If not, I need the input box to be editable.

Is there a way to achieve this? The answer can be in javascript, php etc... I'm not fussed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use shorten if/else form to do it in php (for example).

```
<input <?php echo empty($uni_name['name']) ? '' : 'readonly' ?> name="university" type="text" id="university" value="<?php echo $uni_name['name'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, just add the condition in the same line:

```
<input name="university" type="text" id="university" value="<?= $uni_name['name'] ?>" <?= $uni_name['name'] ? 'readonly="true"' : '' ?>>
```